# What is Ambiguous call error in ASP.NET Core C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

What does the following error mean and how to resolve it?

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Security.Claims.PrincipalExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal, string)' and 'System.Security.Claims.PrincipalExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal, string)'

**UPDATE**:

The References folder shows the following:

[image]

And the Using Statements in the relevant `.cs` file are as follows:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ABCTest.Models;
using ABCTest.Models.AccountViewModels;
using ABCTest.Services;
```

Comment: That's the crazyest thing I've seen in a while.  Both of the methods look to be identical and they are System methods.  Do you have two copies of the same dll (maybe different versions with different names) referenced?  That's really odd.

Comment: Check your References.  It may have been added twice for some reason.  Or your using statements.

Comment: You mixed up dependencies. Usually happens when you mix pre-rc2 packages with post rc2 packages

Comment: Are you getting this when your application starts up?

Comment: @Tseng How can I resolve it? I've added an UPDATE section in my post above.

Comment: By carefully checking your dependencies, its very obvious on your screenshot. See my answer below ;)

Comment: @unicorn2 It happened when compiling the app. The solution below resolved the issue. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an very old dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`. It is pulling all the old pre-rc2 packages in your solution and you end up with two assemblies with different name and different versions and compiler doesn't know which one to choose.

Together with ASP.NET Core `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` was renamed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` (notice the Core part) and its version should be 1.1.0 too with the rest of your ASP.NET Core packages.

Be careful when following **very old** tutorials (ones which refer `Microsoft.AspNet.*` or `Microsoft.EntityFramework.*` packages or ones that are older than July 2016) as they are based on the framework before the assemblies got renamed.

Comment: I think that's it. I uninstalled `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package and it's working now. Your suggestion worked (thank you for helping me resolve it).

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are using a function but the compiler does not know which function you mean since there are two of the same name and same parameters.

In this case, this is probably due to the assembly being loaded twice somehow.